# Use FileOutputStream outputStream into intent chooser

Tags: java, android

When I click on Share button **takeScreenshot();** method will be called and inside that another method **shareScreenshot(outputStream);** is calling and chooser is opening to share imege.

But WhatsApp gives an error i.e **" Sending failed. Please try again later".**

**Code:**

**Step 1:**

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                super.onBackPressed();
                break;

            case R.id.share:
                takeScreenshot();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**Step 2:**

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            shareScreenshot(outputStream);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Step 3:**

```
private void shareScreenshot(FileOutputStream outputStream) {
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
    }
```

So, when a user clicks on the Share button in my Activity, intent chooser is opening that is correct. 
And from that suppose user click on WhatsApp, it should share a screenshot of that Activity.

Comment: Why you want to FileOutputStream object into your shareScreenshot method. you haven't used that in your method.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Add write permission in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

also, request permission like this and handle that result.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1);
```

**Step 2:** instead of sending **outputStream** to **shareScreenshot();** method send **imageFile**

So replace this **shareScreenshot(outputStream);** to **shareScreenshot(imageFile);** this.

**Step 3:** changes to your **shareScreenshot(File outputStream);** method

```
 private void shareScreenshot(File outputStream) {

        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(outputStream);

        Log.d("mTAG", "shareScreenshot: "+imageUri);

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
    }
```

Done.